# How to get the "temp folder" in Windows 7?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In Windows 7, how can I get programatically the system temporary folder?

Comment: correction - temp folder, not the user folder

Comment: I updated the question to say "system temporary folder", I hope that is what you meant, from the last comment. Add more clarification if this is an absolute requirement, for instance.

Comment: For just the user, the `TEMP` environment variable (although I believe there is also a WinAPI for this...?) should suffice. Not sure how to do it unbound from a user, however.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by temp folder not the user folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is probably what you're looking for.

```
TCHAR buf [MAX_PATH];

if (GetTempPath (MAX_PATH, buf) != 0)
    MessageBox (0, buf, _T("Temp path"), 0);
```

Comment: This does not retrieve the SYSTEM temp folder in most cases.  By default, it will return the user's temp folder which is usually \Users\<user>\AppData\Local\temp.

Comment: The question originally said just "temporary folder", not "system temporary folder".

Answer (score 2):

Have you given a try to **[GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**?

> Retrieves the path of the directory designated for temporary files.

You can find a code sample **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**.

Comment: The link also contains the order the temp file is determined, which seems to be user-first and imply the "Windows Directory" is the final temp path?

Comment: In fact, it should be read as the "Temp" folder within the %WINDIR% directory.

Comment: It will not return %WINDIR%\temp in most cases.

Comment: Only as the last fallback option

Answer (score 1):

You could get the environment variable for the temp folder:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683188%28VS.85%29.aspx